# ASP MVC controller not triggering

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I know this is a common issue, but I have tried so many things and I just cannot figure this out. I am generating two links:

```
http://localhost:1757/ViewReport/DeleteFileFromServer?id=orderedList2.png&reportid=3f66320f-a092-4c5e-8321-3a0b6def68c2
http://localhost:1757/ViewReport/Downloading?id=orderedList7.png&reportid=3f66320f-a092-4c5e-8321-3a0b6def68c2
```

And am attempting to trigger the underlying controller from these 2 urls.
My routeconfig has one entry in it, which is the default one:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
            );
```

And my two controller functions are:

```
  [HttpGet]
    public void Downloading(string id,string reportid){//code}
[HttpGet]
    private void DeleteFileFromServer(string id, string reportid){//code}
```

**Downloading** gets called when using its url, but DeleteFileFromServer **NEVER** gets called, even though they have almost an identical url except for the controller name. There is **NO** special entry in route config, so I cannot figure this out. Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Make the deletefilefromserver method public.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DeleteFileFromServer is marked private. Make it public.

Comment: Thank you. I feel like an idiot. One of those mind numbing days where you think it is something far more complicated than it actually is. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Look at the **scope** of the methods, one is `private` and the other is `public`, both should be `public`

```
[HttpGet]
public void Downloading(string id,string reportid){//code}
[HttpGet]
public void DeleteFileFromServer(string id, string reportid){//code}
```